# What name do you use for the parameter in a static variable setter method?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

When I write setters for instance methods, I use this to disambiguate between the instance variable and the parameter:

```
public void setValue(int value) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

So, what do I do when value is a class variable (static) instead of a member of an instance?

```
private static int value = 7;
public static void setValue(int value) {
  value = value;  // compile fails; ambiguous
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using mutable statics at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<classname>.value = value;`

Comment: It's always obvious in retrospect. :)